# Cannot compile a PyQT designer file into a Python

Tags: python, pyqt

I hope someone can help me as I've already spent several hours trying to sort this issue out without success. I am trying to use compileUi from the modPyQt4.uic to compile a PyQT Designer ui file into a Python py file, but when I do I get errors saying the DLLs fail to load.

Investigating further I found that these errors occur because Python cannot find Core QT module. I get the following error when trying to import the Core Qt module into Maya 2011:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
# Error: line 1: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 2, in <module>
# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found. #
```

I have seen that others have had similar issues and that the advice given in response is to to either move the DLLs /bin directory under PyQT4 into the root directory of the installation or alter the environment variable so that it points to the /bin directory ahead of all other directorys in the Python installation.

In my situation, however, the /bin directory doesn't even exist in my installation and even after reinstalling it it still is not there. Why is it not there? Have the developers moved the files elsewhere?

My installation is as follows:

Windows 7
Python 2.6.4 running in Maya 2011
PyQT v4.8.4 for Python 2.6

Once again I hope someone can help me as I want to lean PyQt, but if I can't solve this problem it is going to be an impassable barrier to progressing further.

Thanks in advance,
Terry Rozmus

Comment: Did you try searching your computer for `pyqt`, not exactly a common string of letters, to see where else it might be?

Comment: It may be because of the way Maya has it's install directories (at least on Windows). Make sure that all the binaries for PyQT are in .../Autodesk/Maya 2011/Python/Lib/site-packages/PyQT4 (going off memory) and ensuring that your PYTHONPATH has the site-packages directory in it. If that doesn't work, try copying mayapy.exe and python##.dll to .../Autodesk/Maya 2011/Python.

Comment: It is resolved now. I wound up replacing the PyQT distribution I had with another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing " from PyQt4.QtCore import * "...use from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore..